# Best practice for rendering restricted pages?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router, amazon-iam

I have three types of users for my app: let's call them authenticated_v1, authenticated_v2, and unauthenticated. I want to conditionally render a page that will only allow access for authenticated_v1. OnLoad() calls a GET API; this API is only accessible to authenticated_v1 user via AWS IAM permissions.

I have no idea how this is done in real-world practice. Can I rely on just the IAM (and re-directing when OnLoad throws an error), or do I need some a HOC-derived variable that I trickle down in props (ie isAuthenticated)?

Comment: Your app's users are actually IAM users? That's unusual. Or do you mean that you expose certain resources to them based on their app role (not IAM role) in your application?

Comment: I mean that they are assigned a Cognito Identity Pool id which allows them certain permissions via the IAM role I have allocated